# Quaternions as an Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

I'm lacking some vital understanding about quaternions and algebras in general. If we first define $V=\{a+bi+cj+dk|a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Then we define scalar multiplication, vector multiplication, addition e.t.c. But as I understand it, aren't $1,i,j,k$ meant to be vectors, meaning that $bi$ for example has to already be defined even for the set to be defined. Very confused! As usual thanks for any replies!

Comment: You don't need to consider $i, j, k$ as vectors. Just consider them to be symbols which satisfy certain relations such as $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$.

Comment: That doesn't cut it for me though. I like knowing what I'm working with!

Comment: FWIW, the formal symbol route can be made rigorous easily. Interpret ``$a + bi + cj + dk$'' as meaning the function from a set of four (distinct) elements $\{1, i, j, k\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ given by $1 \mapsto a, i \mapsto b, j \mapsto c, k \mapsto d$. Such functions have a natural $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure (pointwise operations). In this language $i$ is an abuse of notation which means the corresponding indicator function. This is just a (more coordinate free...) repackaging of the usual tuple approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you write for $V$ is not a precise definition (strictly speaking). One defines $\mathbb{H} := \mathbb{R}^4$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, so that quaternions are $4$-tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ of real numbers $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. If we define $1 := (1,0,0,0)$, $i := (0,1,0,0)$, $j := (0,0,1,0)$ and $k := (0,0,0,1)$, then by construction we have $(a,b,c,d) = a1 + bi + cj + dk$. After that, one defines the multipliciation in such a way that the relations $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$, $ij=k$ are satisfied. This is a bit [cumbersome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Hamilton_product), especially when one wants to check that $\mathbb{H}$ is in fact a skew field. A more elegant way is to define $\mathbb{H}$ as the subalgebra $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} z & w \\ -\overline{w} & \overline{z} \end{pmatrix} : z,w \in \mathbb{C}\right\}$ of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: So when I write 1, i, j, k, am I referring to (1,0,0,0) e.t.c.? or am I saying 1, i, j, k are vectors whose form I can't know i.e. they may be matrices, or anything isomorphic to $\mathbf{H}$, and the only thing I know about them is their relationships with each other? Thanks for the reply by the way.

Comment: I would say this depends on your general point of view of mathematics. As a category theorist, I agree that only the relations between $1,i,j,k$ matter. But since you have asked and were confused by the formal definition of the quaternions, I have given the most explicit definition. There are also other definitions (apart from the two in my answer, I can imagine three further ones), which all turn out to be isomorphic. You may choose your favorite one. Also compare this with the construction of complex numbers; there are several ways to make $\mathbb{C}=\{a+bi : a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ precise.

Comment: I had the same trouble with the complex numbers, I ended up seeing them as pairs of real numbers, and concluding that the square root of -1 doesn't really exist. I guess my problem is that I when I'm reading through proofs/textbooks in the future and someone refers to the set $\mathbb{H}$, I want to be able to know what they're talking about. I.e. are the elements of $\mathbb{H}$ specific vectors i.e. tuples, or are they more general? It seems like the symbol $\mathbb{H}$ refers to anything isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$. And yet if I say, what is the expression a+bi+cj+dk to someone, they'll

Comment: say "it's a quaternion, duh", but then if I ask what are "1,i,j,k" will they say "also quaternions"? That sounds like a circular definition to me!

Comment: Yes it is a bit circular when one isn't used to it. Therefore, I suggest that you choose the definitions I gave in my answer (until you find another definition which works better for you). It is really simple, quaternions "are" just 4-tuples of real numbers, with the usual scalar multiplication and addition, and with a kind of complicated multiplication, but which may be reduced to the simple rules $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$, $ij=k$. By the way, $\mathbb{C}$ definitely *has* a square root of $-1$, in fact two such square roots $(\pm i)$.

Comment: Ok I think I'll have a working understanding if I stick to the definition you give and work from there, maybe go through the multiplication rules a bit more myself. There is no single real number that is the square root of -1 I guess is what I wanted to say. You need two real numbers to get something analogous to the square root of -1. Anyway thanks for all the help!

Comment: Ok finally understood it, took me a bit of working out on paper but I'm happy with my current understanding of them now, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In the quaternion algebra $\;\Bbb H\;,\;\;1,i,j,k\;$ are just abstract elements, and then there are defined operations and relations: $\;i^2=j^2=k^2=-1\;,\;\;ij=k\;$ , etc.

I don't understand what's the problem with seeing these algebra's (or any other's, of course) elements as "vectors": as part of a four dimensional real vector space, *all the elements* are vectors, and thus you can see $\;bi\;,\;\;b\in\Bbb R\;$ the scalar product of the vector $\;i\;$ with the scalar $\;b\;$ , or as part of a ring, the product of the two ring elements $\;b\,,\,i\;$. Both these products, formally different, are the same since an algebra behaves well in this respect.

In short: $\;\Bbb H\;$ can be seen as a four dimensional real vector space which is *also* a non-commutative ring (in fact, a division algebra).

Comment: But if you say $1,i,j,j$ are all just vectors, and so are all linear combinations of them, it still doesn't tell me what these vectors are! I can't define a quaternion to be a combination of other quaternions!

Comment: Yes @JamesMachin...so? That wasn't your question, as far as I see it. Anyway, according to the definitions that you surely have, it is very easy to show that, referring to the **vector space** $\;\Bbb H_{\Bbb R}\;$ , the set $\;\{1,i,j,k\}\;$ is linearly independent **and** a generator set of $\;\Bbb H\;$ (i.e., a basis) ...

Comment: Yes I could, but my question is basically, what is "1,i,j,k". If you define a quaternion as q=a+bi+cj+dk, then you can't say "i is a quaternion. What are the elements of $\mathbb{H}$ then? like could you write one down explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

Mull over this: when you define polynomials over $x$ in terms of $x$, do you have trouble accepting $x$ alone as a polynomial?

If it helps, you could just think of $1,i,j,k$ as symbols, with no special properties other than being distinct. Then you *define* quaternions by

- declaring the underlying set to be formal expresions of the form $a+bi+cj+dk$, whose nicknames are "quaternions."
- declaring all the addition multiplication rules you need to make the implied addition and multiplication mean something official (like $1\cdot x=x$, $ij=-ji$, $ai+bi=(a+b)i$, distributivity, etc.)

When both of these steps are done, the four original symbols are represented in the formal set: e.g. $0\cdot 1+1i+0k+0j$ is the same thing as $i$, and henceforth would be a "quaternion."

---

Both polynomial rings and quaternions can be viewed as building rings out of generators and relations.

I'm guessing you're familiar with polynomial rings in two variables, like $F[x,y]$. When we build those there is an assumption that $xy=yx$... but do we really need to assume that? No! The notation $F\langle x,y\rangle$ is often used to denote the polynomial ring in "noncommuting indeterminates," and it has more elements in the sense that $xy$ and $yx$ are different things, $xyx$ and $x^2y$ are different, and so on.

(And really, there's nothing stopping us from defining an even more general type of polynomial ring where the indeterinates are nonassociating, and $(xy)z\neq x(yz)$ and so on. But we have to stop digressing for the sake of discussion :) )

But $F\langle x,y \rangle$ and $F[x,y]$ are definitely related: its easy to see that $F[x,y]\cong F\langle x,y \rangle/(xy-yx)$, that is, the polynomial ring is a quotient of the noncommuting polynomial ring. The thing in the ideal we're modding out by is referred to as a *relation* because it specifies some extra property that we are enforcing in the quotient algebra.

Another example of this would be $\Bbb R[i]/(i^2+1)\cong\Bbb C$: you see, the symbol $i$ (nobody said anything about an imaginary number yet) is forced to have the property $i^2=-1$ in the quotient ring. Thus $i$ in the quotient ring becomes a complex number, along with all the other elements.

By now you're noticing that if this makes sense for complex numbers, then why not quaternions? Indeed, if you take $\Bbb H\cong \Bbb R\langle i,j,k\rangle/(i^2+1,j^2+1,k^2+1,ijk+1)$ since those are all the relations we need to bend the noncommuting polynomial ring into the quaternions. (Those aren't necessarily the *best* or the *only* relations that will do the trick, but I guess they are the most familiar.)